# How does the design view in Visual Studio work?

Tags: html, visual-studio

How does the designer work in Visual Studio?
Does it build the view similar to some browser or does it have its' own rules?

The reason I'm asking is because the code below will show in design view.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<div>Some text to warn users with IE6 or earlier versions.</div>
<![endif]-->
```

...or is it as easy as: *All code will show up in design view*.

Comment: What versions of IE do you have installed?

Comment: I have IE8 installed but I've tried with `[if gt IE 9]` and it still shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditional comments worked for me with VS 2010. What version of VS do have installed?

My guess is that your using an older version of VS and the internal browser is a plain old IE6.0 embedded WebBrowser control. If so its not likely to have its own rules.

It looks like the Visual Studio 2010 SP1 internal browser is IE7.0 (Man that explains why it is so useless). I get the following details from the internal browser.

> Browser Name: **Microsoft Internet Explorer**
>
> Browser Version: 4.0 (compatible; **MSIE 7.0**; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8)

To test this out for yourself, add the following code to an ASPX page, build, and then view the page with the internal browser

```
<div id="example"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    txt += "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
    txt += "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>";

    document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = txt;
</script>
```

From http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

Comment: You mean you didn't get the warning text in the designer? My version of VS is 10.0.30319.1 and IE8 8.0.6. Oh and btw, I've been told not to use w3schools as source, since it's not reliable:  http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @Niklas: That's correct I did not get the IE6 warning text to appear. IE8 8.0.6 is the version you get when running the script I posted, or the version that is installed on your computer? The version installed on your computer does not matter. VS uses it own embedded browser.

Comment: BTW you can visit the following url inside visual studio's browser to get the same information: http://fmbip.com

Comment: My version of VS is 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel. The installed version of IE is 9.0.8112.16421 however I'm reasonably sure that VS is using a com embedded version of IE7.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It says `Browser Name: Netscape` and `Browser Version: 5.0 (Windows)`. Well that explains why I'm seeing the warning =) But why I have Netscape is beyond me.